# How to focus Quill editor using the vue-quill package?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quill

I am using the vue-quill-editor package for my vue application, but I can only focus on the editor if I click on the same line as the editor.
I would like to be able to focus on the Editor by clicking anywhere within the parent

I know there is a quill.focus() function, but is there a way that I can access it without changing the vue-quill-editor file?
If I do change it, are there things that I should be aware of when working with others?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ8ss.jpg
here I have uploaded a photo that may better explain my struggle.

Any suggestions on what I should try?

Answer (score -1):

Listen to the parent clicks an then find the quill editor (by id or by any selector) then element.focus() 
BTW, the element has to be an input element.

Comment: do you mind adding some code example? I'm not sure how to find, and where to put element.focus();

Comment: This doesn't work. Putting focus on parents does nothing.